# Why shouldn't you have redundant states represented in a SQL schema?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, schema

My colleague recently introduced a state machine into a model in our SQL schema. That is, a column that would represent a state computed from other sources in the database. She would then recompute this column whenever an event occurred at the application level.

An analogous example would be we had a table called "restaurant" and a table called "employee". The "employee" table has has a boolean column "working" that is set to true when an employee is working. She introduced a new column to restaurant called "is_open", which is set to true or false whenever we receive an event at the application layer indicating that an employee started/stopped working. If atleast one employee is working, the restaurant is open.

I tried to explain that less state in the database is better, and it's better to compute "is_open" on the fly (in the ORM or as a view or something) so that invalid states can't be represented in the database, but she's not convinced by my explanation. I'm curious if I can reference an anti-pattern here, or make the case in a more familiar or compelling way (or maybe I'm wrong!)

Is this an anti-pattern? If so, what's the best way to explain it/reference it for coworkers?

Comment: Let your colleague to draw the dependency graph for the model of 10 tables and then debug that network for problematic place. If it will be built on triggers, then it may come to endless cascading updates state or introduce unnecessary concurrency

Comment: @astentx right, we sort of understand why exploding state causes issues from our experiences, but ideally this is already wrapped up in some kind of well-thought-out explanation. I looked through my "SQL Antipatterns" book and didn't find any particular section referencing this pattern.

Comment: "There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things" --Phil Karlton "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" --Donald Knuth

Comment: Storing a computed inferred state in this fashion is a great way to introduce redundancy, contradictions and bugs and will be nothing but technical debt for the poor sod who supercedes you/him/her.